# Stuck in emergency mode after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04

I have an older laptop that has a partitioned hard drive. Windows 10 on one side and Ubuntu 20.04 on the other. Yesterday I downloaded and loaded Ubuntu 22.04 now I am stuck in emergency mode. When I have tried to boot into default it says:

```
Failed to start default target: Transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive (emergency.target has ‘start’ job queued, but ‘stop’ is included in transaction)
```

Can any one help? I have tried to log in to get to `journalct1 -xb` with no luck it won’t accept my login.